# Laravel4 memory consumption concerns

Tags: php, laravel-4

## Case

Currently I am developing an application using Laravel 4. I installed [profiler](https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler) to see the stats about my app. This is the screenshot:

[image]

## Questions

- You can see that it consumes **12.25 MB** memory for each request (very simple page) in my vagrant (Ubuntu 64 bit + Nginx + PHP 5.3.10+ MySQL). Do you think this is too much ? This means If I have 100 concurrent connections, the memory consumption will be about 1 GB. I think this is too much but what do you think ?
- It loads **237** files for each request. Do you think this is too much ?
- When I deploy this app to the my server (Centos 6.4 with Apache + PHP 5.5.3 with Zend OPcache + MySQL) the memory consumption decreases dramatically. This is the screenshot from the server:

[image]

What do you think about this difference between my mac and the server ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can you clarify which cache are you talking about ? View, code or data cache ?

Comment: You say that you vagrant box runs PHP 5.3.10 and your server runs PHP 5.5.3. Drastically lower memory consumption is to be expected with such a large version difference.

Comment: @NikiC Thanks! You're right. This is one of the reasons of the decrease. I tested the same page while OPCache is disabled. This also increased the memory usage from **3.25M** to **8.30M**.

Comment: @CanGeliş Opcache uses a different allocator, so stuff that's stored by opcache does not count towards the memory usage that PHP reports. On the other hand - as the memory used by opcache is shared between all PHP process that probably makes sense from a practical perspective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you don't really need to worry about this.

12MB is not really a large amount for a PHP program. And 100 concurrent connections is a *lot*.

To put it into context, assume your PHP page takes half a second to run, that would mean you'd need to have 12000 page loads per minute to achieve a consistent 100 concurrent connections. That's a lot more traffic than any of my sites get, I can tell you that.

Of course, if your page takes longer than half a second to load, this number will come down quickly, and your 100 concurrent connections can become a possibility much more easily.

This is one reason why it's a really good idea to focus on performance<sup>**‡**</sup> -- the quicker your program can finish running, the quicker it can free up its memory for the next visitor. In fact unless you have a really major memory usage problem (which you don't), performance is probably more important in this context than the amount of memory being used.

In any case, if you do have 100 concurrent connections, you're likely to get issues with your server software before you have them with PHP. Apache has a default limit to the max number of connections, and it is a lot lower than 100. (you can raise it, of course, but if you really are getting that kind of traffic, you'll likely be wanting more servers anyway)

As for the 12M memory usage, you're not really ever likely to get much less than that for a PHP program. PHP needs a chunk of memory just in order to run in the first place, and the framework will need a chunk too, so most of your 12M will be due to that. This means that although your small program may be using 12M, it does not follow that a larger program would use twice as much. So you probably don't need to worry too much about it.

If you do have high traffic, and performance issues as a result, there are various ways you can mitigate the problem. The main one is by using caching. PHP 5.5 comes with an OpCache module built-in, which will cache your programs for you so that it doesn't have to do all the bootstrap work such as loading all the files every time. For some systems, this can have a dramatic impact on performance.

There are also other layers of caching you can use, such as a server-level page cache like Varnish, which will cache your static pages so that PHP doesn't even need to be called if the page content hasn't changed.

(<sup>**‡**</sup> of course there are other reasons for focussing on performance too, like keeping your visitors happy)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you think about the difference about my server and the vagrant box ?

Comment: 12 mb is bit abnormal.....another large framework yii framework uses only 3-4 mb for raw pages or maybe 6 mb for intensive pages....Try using a much faster less memory, more easier yii @CanGeliş